# FOSS LIB not HOW TODO: OutputStream that auto rolls when file gets too big or hour/day et change

Tags: java, io

Id like an OutputStream that performs many of the functions found in the RollingXXXAppender classes in log4j.

Are there any FOSS libraries that support this sort of smarts for a simple OutputStream. Id rather the code not be aware of the rolling process and not require any hints as to when to roll ? Ideally the rolling control helpers would be passed to the factory and hidden deep inside the abstraction.

SAMPLE USE CASE

1. closing itself
   -> file.txt
2. renaming the original to some backup 
   -> file.txt -> file.001
3. recreating an empty file and continue writing 
   -> file.txt

This sort of functionality works best for any system that requires the creation of really large files such as logging.

POTENTIONAL PROBLEMS

- it should have some smarts and not roll in the middle of a line write. Probably the best solution to this is to have the roll tests to be performed before/after a write rather than in the middle.

RE: TIPS ON HOW TO WRITE MY OWN..

I dont want to write my own, i know how to - which is why i mentioned RollingXXXAppender. I would rather leverage the effort of a preexisting library.

Comment: Why not look at the source of RollingXXXAppender as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily implement this by extending a [FileOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). One thing to bear in mind, though, is that this approach only makes sense if you are willing to keep the file open -instead of opening and closing it in each write ; which in turn only makes sense if the writing to this log file is centralized.

Comment: Thats not quite true (the bit about closing after each write). For a size limiting OutputStream one only needs to count the bytes written before doing the close, rename, create empty thing.

Comment: I am not saying that you need to close-reopen the file after each write for getting the rollup behaviuor. Just that you *might* need to do it if you want to support simultaneous writing by different processes.